# Checkbox(check all) not selected

Tags: checkbox

I have a question about checkboxes.

Here I have 2 checkboxes, if i select both (car,bus) checkboxes, it must be selected also "Checkall" checkbox.

How can I do that? (i can't remove below selectable)

```
**http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/xUU4p/10/**
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On each checkbox bus and car bind click event which will observer if all other checkboxes are also checked then checked the "Checkall" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? Please be noted that live method is changed to the method of change for "checkAll".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.checkAll').change(function() {
    $('.chc').attr('checked', $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'checked' :'');
  });

  $("#slctble").selectable({
      filter:'td',
      cancel:'td:not(.isaretle)',
      stop: function() {   
         $(".ui-selected input", this).each(function() {
              this.checked= !this.checked
          });//end-ui-selected input
         $('.chc').length == $('.chc:checked').length ?   $('.checkAll').attr('checked', 'checked') : $('.checkAll').attr( 'checked','');           
      }//endStopFunction
  });//endSelectable
});
```

Comment: now it works not with older than jquery-1.4.2.js                

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/utEBt/

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen your comment. Why don't you try with this? http://jsfiddle.net/utEBt/1/